# Prove or disprove $ lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = lim_{n \to \infty} a_{\pi(n)} $, where $\pi$ is a bijective function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I have no idea how to solve the following task:

Prove or disprove that: 
If $ (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ converges and $ \pi : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N} $ is a bijective function, then $$ lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = lim_{n \to \infty} a_{\pi(n)}. $$

Since this is my homework, I'm not asking for a solution. Could you just give me some hints how to solve this?
I think I should use the properties of a bijective function here, but I have no idea, how...
Any help would be appreciated!

Regards,
Lena

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185778/rearrangement-of-sequences-with-limit-0

Comment: possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Any open interval around the limit contains all *but finitely many* elements of the sequence.